Table of pairs to list of pairs
I have a table looking like this:
{{{1},1},{{4},2},{{9},3},{{16},4}}
I need to plot it. I think i can do it with list of pairs, but i can't understand how to make it from table in Mathematica.

Given
data = {{{1}, 1}, {{4}, 2}, {{9}, 3}, {{16}, 4}}

you can turn it into a list of pairs with
Flatten /@ data
(* {{1, 1}, {4, 2}, {9, 3}, {16, 4}} *)

I'm assuming that's the list of pairs you want. Next use ListPlot on the above pairs.
